# Prometheus pre build binary for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, prometheus

I am trying out Prometheus on Mac OS X. I looked up the downloads and not having a direct indication of which version is for Mac. I tried docker to run the Prometheus on Mac. Just want to run it directly on Mac without docker. Does any one know which version to pick.

There were few BSDs there for pick. I know Mac is also BSD. Not sure which one matches or doesn't matter as long as it is bsd?.

Other than those binaries, I think brew install should do the work

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [downloads](https://prometheus.io/download/) page has a build for [Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)) on amd64.

To quote the wikipedia page:

> Darwin forms the core set of components upon which macOS (previously
>   OS X and Mac OS X), iOS, watchOS, and tvOS are based.

This is the official binary for OSX. Other methods (such as `brew install prometheus` are also available).

Comment: Thanks. Got it running on my mac

Comment: i have downloaded the binary for mac.can you please let me know how to install the same

Answer (score 3):

Install and download Docker from this link - https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/docker-for-mac/install/#download-docker-for-mac.

> You can launch the your terminal.
>    You can launch a Prometheus container for trying it out with

```
$ docker run --name prometheus -d -p 127.0.0.1:9090:9090 prom/prometheus
```

> Prometheus will now be reachable at http://localhost:9090/.